# MVC 4 - null model when trying to post a collection of models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, nullreferenceexception

I've looked on SO and there are similar questions but I am trying to post back a collection of models but when I press my submit button it complains that my model is null.

I have this view in my application

**View**

```
@model List<Business.Models.Applications.ApplicantViewModel>
@using GridMvc.Html
@using (Html.BeginForm("AllocateFirst", "Application", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <div id="grid-wrap" style="width: 500px;">
        Allocate Application
        <div id="SystemMsg">
        </div>

        @Html.Grid(Model).Named("FirstStageGrid").Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(m => m.Id);
    columns.Add(m => m.MembershipNumber).Titled("Membership number");
    columns.Add(m => m.DateReceived).Titled("Registered date");
    columns.Add(m => m.Fullname).Titled("Name").Filterable(true).Encoded(false);
    columns.Add(m => m.ApplicationType).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false);
    columns.Add(m => m.AssignedStaffMem).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(m =>

        @<b>
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlStaff", new SelectList(Model.First().ListOfStaff, "UserId", "Fullname"))
        </b>
    );
    columns
.Add()
.Encoded(false)
.Titled("Action")
.Sanitized(false)
.SetWidth(30)
.RenderValueAs(m =>

  @<b> <a href="#" onclick="AssignStaff(@m.Id, @Html.Raw("\"") @m.Fullname.Trim() @Html.Raw("\""), @m.Id)">
      Assign</a> </b>
);
}).WithPaging(5)

  <br />
        Assign on bulk: @Html.CheckBox("AssignOnBulk")
        <br />
        <div id="bulkAssign">

            Assign to: @Html.DropDownList("ddlStaff", new SelectList(Model.First().ListOfStaff, "UserId", "Fullname"))
            @Html.Hidden("hdnStaffId")
            <input type="submit" value="Submit all on bulk" />
        </div>


    </div>
    <script>

        $('#AssignOnBulk').on('change', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#bulkAssign").show();
                var staffId = $('#ddlStaff').val(); //no :selected here

            }
            else {
                $("#bulkAssign").hide();
                $("hdnStaffId").val(this);
                var staffId = $('#ddlStaff').val(); //no :selected here
            }
        });

        $('#ddlStaff').change(function () {
            var staffId = $('#ddlStaff').val(); //no :selected here
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($(AssignOnBulk).is(':checked'))
                $("#bulkAssign").show();
            else
                $("#bulkAssign").hide();
        });


        function AssignStaff(appId, fullName) {
            //Get row based on Id of grid
            var tableRow = $("td").filter(function () {
                return $(this).text() == appId;
            }).closest("tr");

            // get staffId based on option selected in tr
            var staffId = $(tableRow).find('option:selected').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Application/SetFirstCheck',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { "staffId": staffId, "appId": appId },
                success: function (success) {
                    $('#SystemMsg').html(success);
                    $(tableRow).remove();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

}
```

What I am trying to do is if the user checks this checkbox

```
Assign on bulk: @Html.CheckBox("AssignOnBulk")
```

The div with the button is shown with a dropdown menu and the user can decide to assign one person to all the people in the grid, instead of using the actionlink.

What I want to do is press the post button and it posts back the collection plus the staffId from the dropdown menu. But when I press post, VS2012 highlights my grid and says the model is null.

**Controller method**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AllocateFirst(List<Business.Models.Applications.ApplicantViewModel> Model, bool AssignOnBulk, string ddlStaff)
        {

            return View(Model);
        }
```

[image]

I've attached a screenshot of what happens when I click the post, it highlights my entire grid.

Comment: Can you post your Application View Model code

Comment: Try @model IEnumerable<Business.Models.Applications.ApplicantViewModel>

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not possible to send List or object to the controller from view. Even if you want post only object you have to fill every property on the page ...

You can send information to controller thanks which you will be able to load list there or you need to use Ajax and JSON.Stringify.

Something like:

`<script>
var myList = [];
myList.push({
             Id: 1,
             Name: 'Test',
             Surname: 'Test2' });
jQuery.ajax({
                url: '../Controller/Action,
                data: '{ modelList:' + JSON.stringify(myList) + '}',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (data) {
                }
            });
</script>`